# change placement bootstrap tooltip

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I want to make tooltip from boostrap, when input select has selected so tooltip show in element html. I have made that code in javascipt/jquery. this is code:

```
    $('#pembayaran').on('change', function(){
        if($(this).val()=='GRATIS' && $('#keterangan').val()==''){
            $('#keterangan').attr('title', 'Keterangan wajib disi!').tooltip('show');
        }
    });
```

I want to make tooltip position on right.

I try code

```
    $('#pembayaran').on('change', function(){
        if($(this).val()=='GRATIS' && $('#keterangan').val()==''){
            $('#keterangan').attr('title', 'Keterangan wajib disi!').tooltip('show', {
               placement: 'right'
            });
        }
    });
```

but this code not working. Can you help me. please

Comment: Can you share the full non-working code in http://jsfiddle.net? By the way, this has nothing to do with Twitter Bootstrap.

Comment: @Victor This looks to be asking about the [bootstrap tooltip api](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips), so it does have a little to do with bootstrap :)

Comment: @ZaidCrouch, sorry, missed out the `tooltip`. :P

Answer (score 6):

The bootstrap plugin methods take a single argument, not two. This method call:

```
$('#keterangan').attr('title', 'Keterangan wajib disi!').tooltip('show', {
    placement: 'right'
});
```

is incorrect. Instead, you should keep the on change function the way you had it, and call:

```
$('#keterangan').tooltip({ placement: 'right' });
```

earlier to set up the tooltip options (such as when the document is ready).

The other, possibly simpler, alternative would be to add `data-position="right"` to the element that the pop-up is being shown on.

Answer (score 3):

in html:

```
<a href="sample.html" data-placement="right" rel="tooltip" title="This is a tooltip">Hover me!</a>
```

in jquery:

```
$(function(){
    $("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
    $('.mytooltip').tooltip('destroy');
    $('.mytooltip').tooltip({ placement: 'right' });
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me, because I use `tooltip` in many places in **bottom** position and I wanted to change the position in some cases to **top**, for example `table tr:last-child td a` in a grid with scroll.

Comment: I tried many solutions but nothing worked until I found this one which provides destroying tooltip before changing the placement, so thank you !

Answer (score 0):

For my case I needed to change the placement of the tooltip based on the screen size, as a solution I listen to the resolution change event, then in the event handler I destroy the old tooltip and add a new one with the placement determined according to the new width size:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var enablePasswordTooltip = function() {
        var passwordTooltipContent = $('#PasswordTooltipContent').html();
        var isMobileResolution =  ($(window).width() < 700);
        $('input.password-tooltip').tooltip({
            'trigger': 'focus',
            'placement': isMobileResolution ? 'top' : 'right',
            'html': true,
            'title': passwordTooltipContent
        });
    };

    // Enable the Password tooltip when the page is loaded
    enablePasswordTooltip();

    $(window).resize(function() {
        // After the resolution changes, destroy the tooltip and add it again in order to adjust to the new resolution
        $('input.password-tooltip').tooltip('destroy'); 
        setTimeout(function(){
            enablePasswordTooltip();
        }) 
    });
});
```